# Alinear elementos en una linea Horizontal en css

Tags: html, css

```css
.box_order {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.words_order {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Centuri Ghotic', sans-serif;
  color: #2DB5FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_order">
  <span class="align">
                    <label for="carne" class="words_order">Carne</label>
                        <input type="image" name="carne" class="button_plus" src="styles/image/plusButton.png" alt="foto">
                            <p name="carne">100g</p>
                                <input name="carne" type="image" name="carne" class="button_plus" src="styles/image/plusButton.png" alt="foto">
                </span>
</div>
```

Hola, tengo un problema,  no se como alinear elemetos en una línea horizontal. Actualmente se ve así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero quiero que se vea así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y tu css? Eso es lo principal que tenías que poner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con Flex box está la solución, pero con algunas pequeñas modificaciones y mejoras en tu código.

No es correcto la etiqueta `span` sino que tiene que ser: `div`. Y a este div con clase `align` le damos los estilos con `display: flex`.

También le di algunos estilos a los imput y al párrafo para acomodar correctamente.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box
}

.align { 
 display: flex; 
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 
 /*margin-left: 30px; 
 margin-top: 20px;*/
 
 padding: 0 10px;
 background-color: lightblue
} 

.words_order { 
 margin: auto;
 margin-left: 0;
 font-size: 30px; 
 font-family: 'Centuri Ghotic', sans-serif; 
 color: #2DB5FF; 
}

.box_order .button_plus {
 margin: 0;
}

.box_order p {
 width: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_order">

    <div class="align">
  
        <label for="carne" class="words_order">Carne</label> 
        
        <input type="image" name="carne" class="button_plus" src="styles/image/plusButton.png" alt="foto"> 
        
        <p name="carne">100g</p> 
        
        <input name="carne" type="image" name="carne" class="button_plus" src="styles/image/plusButton.png" alt="foto"> 
        
    </div> 
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

No se porqué metes todo el contenido dentro de un `<span>`, pero lo unico que tiene que ponerle, es al padre de todo el contenido `display: flex;`

```
<div class="box_order" >
     <span class="align" style="display: flex">
         <label for="carne" class="words_order">Carne</label>
         <input type="image" name="carne" class="button_plus" src="styles/image/plusButton.png" alt="foto">
         <p name="carne">100g</p>
         <input name="carne" type="image" name="carne" class="button_plus" src="styles/image/plusButton.png" alt="foto">
     </span>
</div>
```